# Uno Platform - How to create a full screen Windows Desktop application

Tags: .net, fullscreen, uno-platform

I started to test Uno Platform as an alternative to .NET MAUI, which by the way has been a bad experience to work with it.

I installed last Uno's extension to Visual Studio 2022, run Uno.Check tool, and finally created a minimal project in order to create a simple full screen app. I only added Windows as Platform.

After searching and searching in internet I added to App class a constructor setting PreferredLaunchWindowingMode.

```
    public App()
    {
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
    }
```

But it didn't work.

[image]